# Como deletar linhas nulas em um Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Estou estudando um dataset referente às partidas da NBA, e estou precisando saber como consigo remover os dados do dataframe que se encontram como "None". Pois eles me impedem de conseguir a quantidade exata de atletas.

Segue abaixo o meu dataset:

[image: Dataset]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode retornar os que não tem valores faltantes dessa forma:

```
df[~df.isnull()]
```

o ~ serve para negar, ou seja, is null transforma numa espécie de not null.